# VBA Loop to Delete Multiple Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search/loop through all the columns headers located on row 1 of the opened file and delete it if it matches dColumns, which is a list of columns I do not needed and I put in a range.

```
Sub LLextract()

'Last cell in column
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Data")
With WS
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row + 0
End With

Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim vFile As Variant

'Set source workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'Open the target workbook
vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", , _
      "Select a CSV file", , False)

'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open vFile

'Set selectedworkbook
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

Dim dColumns As Range
Set dColumns = wb.Worksheets("LL Columns to Delete").Range("A:A")

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim A As Range
    For i = 94 To 1 Step -1
        Set A = wb2.Cells(1, i)
        If wb2.Cells(1, i) = dColumns Then A.EntireColumn.Delete
    Next i

'wb2.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Set dColumns = wb.Worksheets("LL Columns to Delete").Range("A")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by just deleting the column when I open wb2. This question is no longer need to be answered or solved.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do just `Range("A")`, replace that with `Range("A:A")`.

(But what are you trying to do with `dColumns`?)

Comment: @AnthonyS.Erdenetuguldur - I haven't run it, but from looking at it, does it work? Can you use `Find` with a column reference?  It's looking in `Cells(i,1)` for ..."Column A"? But anyway - did changing the range fix the issue?

Comment: @AnthonyS.Erdenetuguldur - Yeah, that's what I was thinking.  In your OP, can you clarify what you're expecting to find in `Cells(1,i)`? Perhaps post some sample data?

Comment: @AnthonyS.Erdenetuguldur - `Cells(1,i)` is a single cell, not an area to search. Do you expect `Cells(1,i)` to have `A` in it, then we know to delete column A?

Comment: @AnthonyS.Erdenetuguldur the value that you are putting in `dColumns` in what cell is it?  I think you want `wb.Worksheets("LL Columns to Delete").Range("A1")` or some specific cell, with the value to find.  Or you have your `Find` fields backwards.

Comment: @BruceWayne, Yes. I want to lookup all headers located in dColumns in cells(1,i), and delete it.

Comment: @AnthonyS.Erdenetuguldur you are looping trough the wrong things.  You need to loop through `dColumn` and use each individual cell value in your search of row 1 so say we do `For Each rng in dColumn` then our find would be `Set rngfind = wb2.Range("1:1").Find(dcolumn` then you would `Columns(rngfind.Column).delete`

Comment: @ScottCraner, can you post the loop-code that will go under this section of my module. Dim dColumns As Range
Set dColumns = wb.Worksheets("LL Columns to Delete").Range("A:A")

Comment: @AnthonyS.Erdenetuguldur sorry, I do not have the time at the moment.  Try it on your own for a little while.  If I get time later today I will try to loop back.